# How can I add an icon to the MIUI home screen?

Tags: home-screen, home-screen-shortcuts, miui

I just got a Nexus One, which uses the MIUI interface. It came with two different gallery apps. I prefer the `cooliris` app, but there's no icon for it on the home screen, which makes it difficult to access. I can't seem to figure out how to add an icon.

Everything I've found on the internet is either inaccurate or otherwise unhelpful. This should be simple. What am I missing?

Comment: Have you tried opening the app drawer and long-pressing the icon there?

Comment: @AlEverett: The MIUI interface has no app drawer, according to Google. I haven't seen anything that looks like it could fit that description, and this phone is my only experience with Android. I think I'd have to root my phone to get a vanilla Android interface.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem: The icon already existed on another screen. However, I was confused because both icons are identically named (Gallery) and are nearly identical in appearance. Thus, I didn't realize that I had both icons already.